# How can I set "Https only" for my Azure web app using an ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

I know how to set **Https only** manually in the Azure portal. Navigating to **My Web Application > Custom domains** in the Azure portal opens the Custom domains pane, which has an "Https Only" option.  Setting this option to "On" enables the functionality I am looking for.  I found how to do this manually on [Benjamin Perkins Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/11/30/how-to-make-an-azure-app-service-https-only/).  Unfortunately, it does not contain a description of how to solve the problem in an automated way using ARM templates.

How can I set this "Https only" flag in my ARM template so that I can automate this setting in my deployment?  Assume I have a working ARM deployment already, and just need to know where and what to add to the template specifically for this setting.

I would like to keep answers to an ARM template based approach.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You could check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites). `httpsOnly` is a value in properties. For example:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
    "name": "[parameters('webSiteName')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]": "Resource",
        "displayName": "Website"
    },
    "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('webSiteName')]",
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
        "httpsOnly": true
    }
}
```

ps. Template reference might contain error, use api reference (its not perfect, but its better).

Comment: I have confirmed that this does set the flag in Azure.  Also, thanks for link to the schema.