# How can i Turn On/Off "Https only" for Azure AppService using Azure DevOps Pipeline?

Tags: azure, https, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-appservice

I Have an Azure Release Pipeline for my website. For one of the task in that Release Pipeline, i need to disable HTTPS ONLY option (its is available under SSL/TLS Blade in Azure Portal check below image). After that task is executed i want to turn ON that "HTTPS ONLY" again.

Is there a simple way simple way to do that?

[image]

**PS**: i have reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49445663/2860637)
already but i don't want to use ARM Template

Comment: Does my answer help you?

Comment: @Jawad Sharif Not get your latest information, is Krzysztof Madej's workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use Azure CLI and Azure CLI task to achieve this. Here is the command:

```
az webapp update --resource-group <YourResourceGroupName> --name <YourWebAppName> --set HttpsOnly=true
```